# Pointcut for methods with @Scheduled Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-scheduled

I want to have a AspectJ pointcut for methods annotated with `@Scheduled`. Tried different approaches but nothing worked.

1.)

```
@Pointcut("execution(@org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled * * (..))")
public void scheduledJobs() {}

@Around("scheduledJobs()")
public Object profileScheduledJobs(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOG.info("testing")
}
```

2.)

```
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled *)")
public void scheduledJobs() {}

@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicMethod() {}

@Around("scheduledJobs() && publicMethod()")
public Object profileScheduledJobs(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOG.info("testing")
}
```

Can anyone suggest any other way to have `around`/`before` advice on `@Scheduled` annotated methods?

Comment: Please use code formatting next time. I have just fixed this, but you have been around here for long enough to have learnt about it. No offense. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The pointcut that you are looking for can be specified as below:

```
@Aspect
public class SomeClass {

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled)")
    public void doIt(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("before");
        pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether that's all you require or not. So I'm going to post the other parts of the solution as well.

First of all, notice the `@Aspect` annotation on the class. It is required for the methods in this class to be applied as `advice`.

Also, you need to make sure that the class that has the `@Scheduled` method is detectable via scanning. You can do so by annotation that class with `@Component` annotation. For ex:

```
@Component
public class OtherClass {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Scheduled Execution");
    }
}
```

Now, for this to work, the required parts in your spring configuration would be as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.mvc" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />   <!-- For @Aspect to work -->    
<task:annotation-driven />  <!-- For @Scheduled to work -->
```

Comment: This works for Around advice, but I am trying AfterThrowing advice and when my Scheduled job throws an exception it's not intercepted.