# Calculate Spring Job execution time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this very basic example of Spring Job.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 90000)
    public void myScheduler() throws Exception {

        // Print here execution time into console and save into DB
    }
```

I have to do some very heavy calculations. Is there a way to calculate total execution time? There is a solution with listener, but I would like to do it inside the job because I want to do it in the Job implementation code.

Comment: Check out [Perj4J](https://www.infoq.com/articles/perf4j).

Comment: Are you measuring wall clock time or cpu time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

Answer (score 9):

Can be nicely done using `@Aspect`

First, add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Second, make sure that your class has `@Component` and `@EnableScheduling`.

Finally, create an Aspect class for Spring's Scheduled annotation

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimeScheduler {

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled)")
    public void timeScheduledMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("starting stopwatch");
        Object result = null;
        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        try {
            watch.start();
            result = joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            watch.stop();
            long executionTime = watch.getLastTaskTimeMillis();
            String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();
            String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();

            // print to log/console all the details you need: Time took, 
            // method name, class name etc...
            System.out.println("Time took: [" + executionTime + "] ms");
            System.out.println("Class: " + className);
            System.out.println("Method: " + methodName);

           // db.save(executionTime)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that in this way the executionTime time needs to be persisted from the Aspect class, as a method with `@Scheduled` can not get any arguments to be later saved.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to use this code insight my method because I need to print the result into the same method?

Comment: What do you mean print the result into the same method? Do you mean into the log? Its possible to edit the code and print the method and class names from the Aspect class.

Answer (score 4):

If your project/app is light, you can just put some:

```java
long startTime = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis();
// whatever long processing here
long endTime = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis();
long processingTime = endTime - startTime;
// do print 
// do store to DB
```

However, if your project/app is big (i.e. lots of Schedulers), you may want to inject before/after aspects (also called point-cuts) to them.

Refer to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876117/pointcut-for-methods-with-scheduled-spring-annotation).

Comment: @MS90 , I am not going to start a text-book debate. You are right in some aspects (pun intended). However, for this answer, they can be used interchangeably I guess.

Comment: Relax, you said it right. Pointcuts are (before/after aspects) indeed. Just a play of words. @EdwardAung

Comment: Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 3):

```java
Instant begin = Instant.now();
// do whatever...    
Instant end= Instant.now();
long delta = Duration.between(begin, end).toMillis();
```

Instant class requires Java8

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Framework's [**StopWatch**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) to calculate the execution time. For multiple tasks also you can use stopwatch.

```java
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch("StopWatchDemo");
    StopWatchDemo stopWatchDemo = new StopWatchDemo();

    stopWatch.start("StopWatchTask1");
       stopWatchDemo.performTask1();
    stopWatch.stop();

    stopWatch.start("StopWatchTask2");
        stopWatchDemo.performTask2();
    stopWatch.stop();
```

To get total execution time for all tasks(here task1 and task2)

```java
    System.out.println("StopWatchDemo tasks took total: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds() + " seconds");
```

To get task wise execution time

```java
for(TaskInfo taskInfo :stopWatch.getTaskInfo()) {
    System.out.println(taskInfo.getTaskName()+"-"+taskInfo.getTimeSeconds()+" secs");
}
```